# Error integrating trino with elastic when https is enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, presto, trino

team,

I am facing issue when integrating elastic search with Trino. Without enabling authentication in Trino I am able to access elastic search and run query to fetch elastic data through trino CLI

I followed the below commands to create a self signed certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout http.pem -out trino-certificates.pem -days 365
```

[ provided localhost as CommonName during  .pem file creation]

Below is my elasticsearch.property file.

```
connector.name=elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host=asci-eds
elasticsearch.port=9200
elasticsearch.default-schema-name=default
elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address=true
#elasticsearch.tls.verify-hostnames=true
elasticsearch.tls.enabled=true
elasticsearch.auth.user=elastic
elasticsearch.auth.password=elastic
elasticsearch.tls.keystore-password=elastic
elasticsearch.security=PASSWORD
elasticsearch.tls.keystore-path=/etc/trino/http.pem
elasticsearch.tls.truststore-path=/etc/trino/trino-certificates.pem
```

I get the below error when in trino container logs during startup

```
Caused by: IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
at java.base/DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:1156)
at java.base/PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2013)
at java.base/KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
at java.base/KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
at SslUtils.createSSLContext(SslUtils.java:69)
```

Below is my config.property file.

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
discovery.uri=https://localhost:8443
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=8443
http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/trino/trino.pem
http-server.https.keystore.key=pass

http-server.process-forwarded=true
http-server.authentication.allow-insecure-over-http=true

internal-communication.https.required=false
http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
internal-communication.shared-secret=9sScljbKVW6tY8eXuJncJMa8Su5mCVH04YC5fx7wMhoqKTDH2qLmqt8gKpmdgG3YQcAjoIuj
```

Please suggest if I am missing some configuration

Comment: is this happening with out adding ES connector or only happening after adding it? Also how are you enabling auth in Trino, share the config too

Comment: when both Trino and elastic are working without security I was able to establish conneciton and fetch data. But once i enables security in Trino its failing. Below is my Trino config with security enabled.       I have updated the config.property above